# How can i make this comments with jsdoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, code-documentation

how can i made this comment's properly using jsdoc. Any ideas???

```
   /**********************
* @variables : global variables
***************************/
var map; // this var handle the object related with the map
var image;
var currentMark;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a documentation comment right before the variable:

```
/** this var handle the object related with the map */
var map;
/** An image */
var image;
// Undocumented variables will not show up
var currentMark;
```